# How can I render form elements?

Tags: 8, forms

In Drupal 6, I am using the following code.

```php
$rows[] = array(
  array('data' => drupal_render($form['collected'])),
  array(
    'data'=> drupal_render($form['count']) . drupal_render($form['submit']),
    'colspan' => 3
  )
);
```

In Drupal 8, I am trying to use the following code, but I see the HTML markup of `$form['count']`.

```php
$rows[] = [
  ['data' => \Drupal::service('renderer')->render(($form['collected'])],
  [
    'data' => \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form['count']) . \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form['submit']),
    'colspan' => 3,
  ]
];
```

Comment: Tell us what you want to do as well as how you are trying to do it. You have only told us how you are trying to do something, but we don't know what that something is.

Comment: I want to have two elements in one row. Code from drupal 6 works, but in drupal 8 i don't know how to add this two fields. Above you can see my code from drupal 8, i tried to add them with dot like in drupal 6, but the result is that in row i see html, not rendered element. `\Drupal::service('renderer')->render` is ok but how about dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 8+, you do not need to use a separate theming function as was required in Drupal 6. You can put the form element directly into the table without rendering, and Drupal will handle that on the back-end. It's much simpler:

```
$row = [];
$row[] = [
  'data' => [
    'something' => $form['something'],
    'something_else' => $form['something_else'],
  ],
];

$rows[] = $row;
```